# Uploading CSV contents to database using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, csv, file-upload

I am trying to upload a CSV file with one row using Laravel. Its content is to be stored in the already made database (MySQL) which I have, however I am having great difficulty in doing so.

Here is my form:

```twig
    <center>
    <form action="/csvfileupload" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <h4><label> Please Select File (CSV only):</label>
    <input type="file" name="csvfile"/></h4>
    <h4><input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload"/></h4>
    </form>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    </center>
```

Here is my route:

```
    Route::post('/csvfileupload','Controller@csvfileupload');
```

Here is my controller:

```php
function csvfileupload(Request $req)
{
    $title = $req->input('title');
    $address = $req->input('address');
    $Date = $req->input('Date');
    $intro = $req->input('intro');
    $mainbody = $req->input('mainbody');
    $paragraph = $req->input('paragraph');
    $footer = $req->input('footer');

    $data =
    array('title'=>$title,'address'=>$address,'Date'=>$Date,'intro'=>$intro,
   'mainbody'=>$mainbody,'paragraph'=>$paragraph,'footer'=>$footer);
    DB::table('template')->update($data);

    echo "Success";
}
```

CSV file:

```csv
title,address,Date,intro,mainbody,paragraph,footer
Module Bro,"Hi,",2018-03-14,Attention all students!: This is very 
important!,"Your results are out now on blackboard, you have received a 
grade of:",Comments for your coursework are as follows if you have any 
concerns feel free to contact me at any time.,"Yours Truly, best tutor ever. 
helen d."
```

I want to store them in the database, but how can I do that?

Comment: You have a file upload, you should read up on https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#file-uploads

Comment: first of all your form must have "enctype=multipart/form-data" attribute to let you to upload file

Comment: First, you need to store it on your server. Then, you can use php fgetcsv to read the file. I'll make an answer explaining in detail whenever I can if you still need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below code in your HTML form tag

```
<form action="/csvfileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Controller code:

```
public function csvfileupload(Request $req)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('csvfile')) {
        $path = $request->file('csvfile')->getRealPath();
        $data = \Excel::load($path)->get();

        if ($data->count()) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $arr[] = ['title' => $value->title, 
                          'address' => $value->address,
                          'Date' => $value->Date,
                          'intro' => $value->intro,
                          'mainbody' => $value->mainbody,
                          'paragraph' => $value->paragraph,
                          'footer' => $value->footer,

                         ];
            }
            if (!empty($arr)) {
                DB::table('template')->insert($arr);

                return "Success";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Make sure you update your .env file with your database settings like

E.g

```
    DB_CONNECTION=mysql

    DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

    DB_PORT=3306

    DB_DATABASE=your_database_name

    DB_USERNAME=root

    DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, i am getting a 'Excel' class not found' error on this line :  $data = \Excel::load($path)->get();, do i need to improt an excel class?

Comment: You need to use Excel before your class begins kindly refer : https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://laravelcode.com/post/excel-and-csv-import-export-using-maatwebsite-in-laravel-example&hl=en-IN&geid=1026

Comment: I hope this worked for you as you expected if yes please up vote the answer so that others can reach it easier thanks